# Problem 403 making URL friendly with Boostrap

Tags: html, .htaccess, directory, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to make URL friendly in my personal website. So the problem is that I added some rules in ".htaccess" but I have a error 403 with two ".html" in particular that have the same name as a subdirectory.

This is my actual web folder:
[image: My web folder]

So when I simplify my "href" to my "portfolio.html" I get the 403 error and I belive that gets in conflict with the "portfolio" subdirectory.

This is a button I did into my menu:

```
 <a id="limenu" class="linkmenu" href="/portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
```

And then when I press it, I get this error:

[image]

My ".htaccess" code is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.josecodonyer.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://josecodonyer.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

The only thing I tried is to change the subdirectory name to another one and it worked. But I want to keep the same name into my "portfolio.html" page and in my subdirectory.

Is there anyway to keep the same name in the page and directory and not getting the 403 error?

Thanks a lot!

Update:

I tried to add the DirectorySlash option in to "off" but it keeps getting the same error but now the URL doesn't have the final slash.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.josecodonyer.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://josecodonyer.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

[image]

Comment: You are getting the 403, because mod_dir has realized that this directory exists, so it issues an automatic redirect to the URL with the trailing slash - and then you would either get the directory listing, or in this case here were that appears to be disabled, a 403. You can turn this behavior off using the [`DirectorySlash`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive - but pay attention to what it says there about the potential security implications.

Comment: So I managed to change the DirectorySlash option to off but keeps getting the 403 error.

Comment: Are you still getting redirected to `/portfolio/` (if so, might be cache - try in a private window), or does the browser address bar stay at `/portfolio`?

Comment: FYI, "general" redirects, such as the non-www and the HTTPS rewrite, should happen first, and more specific stuff or internal rewrites, later.

Comment: I'm getting redirected now to "/portfolio" but I get the same error. I cleaned my cache too.

Comment: What if you request `/portfolio.html` directly, does that show the page as expected?

Comment: It actually does, so I guess the conflict is in the name.

Comment: Yes it must have something to do with that, but I am not sure how exactly right now. Can you remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, and see what happens then? I think even when just `/portfolio` gets requested, it might still realize that a directory of that name exists - so that the RewriteRule would not apply here. (And since you are probably not going to have _directories_ with names ending in `.html`, the check for whether a file with that suffix exists, should be sufficient at this point anyway.)